# Is it possible to add text to a layer on top of Bing Map (AJAX)?

Tags: ajax, dictionary, bing-maps, bing

I am not talking about the pushpin text, since it is restrained by the size of the pushpin.
I am not talking about infoBox, since I already implemented infoBox. 
I just want to display some text over the map somewhere, whether there is a pushpin or infoBox.

I am using Bing AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply set the visibility of a div, that is floating over the map, to true when a certain action is done.